# Ruby on Rails: display user profile only if condition is true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, conditional-statements

I want to only have user's profile be public if the user has completed a few tasks.

I have devise set up in my rails application, and right now if there's a new account, ie: `localhost:3000/users/1`, `localhost:3000/users/2`, `localhost:3000/users/3`, etc... these links will work.

How do I make it all private until users have a few items filled in the users database.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a boolean column called `public` with default value being `false` in users table
2. Set `public` attribute to be accessible in user model
3. When user completes the certain tasks, set `public` attribute for the user to be `true`
4. In `show.html.erb` for users, you can show two different content using some code like

```
<%- if @user.public %>
  <p>Show content for public profile</p>
<%- else %>
  <p>This profile is private</p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this approach:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  MIN_TASK_COUNT = 5 # Minimum tasks for profile to be public

  has_many :tasks

  def public?
    tasks_count >= MIN_TASK_COUNT
  end
end

class Task  < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user, counter_cache: true

end
```

Then in your controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id)
    if @user.public?
      render :public_profile, user: @user
    else
      render :private_profile, user: @user
    end
  end
end
```

Note you should create `app/views/users/_private_profile.html.erb` and `app/views/users/_public_profile.html.erb` partials and add a `tasks_count` column to users table.

Comment: Good idea, but I think it is to complicated for this scenario. Isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, but it's not complicated at all.

Comment: Yes, but the answer from @Jason Kim is not so complicated :)

Comment: I don't see the complicated part of my answer. Doesn't matter.